# error building NumPy: cannot find -lpython2.7

Tags: python, build, numpy

I need to build NumPy on a cluster here at work (I don't have root access). I've compiled my own version of Python 2.7.3 (with --enable-shared), and because I don't have root access, Python lives in a non-standard location. I'm having an issue compiling NumPy, though. This is what I get:

```
gfairchild@cj-fe1 ~/code/packages/src/numpy-1.6.2> export CFLAGS="-L/usr/projects/infmodels/gfairchild/packages/lib"
gfairchild@cj-fe1 ~/code/packages/src/numpy-1.6.2> python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95
...
...
...
compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/projects/infmodels/gfairchild/packages/stow/Python-2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c'
gcc: _configtest.c
gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest
_configtest
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
building data_files sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_py
copying numpy/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy
copying build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/__config__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy
copying build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/distutils/__config__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/distutils
running build_clib
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_clib
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'numpy.linalg.lapack_lite' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -L/usr/projects/infmodels/gfairchild/packages/lib -fPIC

compile options: '-DATLAS_INFO="\"3.6.0\"" -I/usr/include/atlas -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/projects/infmodels/gfairchild/packages/stow/Python-2.7.3/include/python2.7 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/multiarray -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/umath -c'
gcc: numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.c
gcc: numpy/linalg/python_xerbla.c
/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -Wall -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/python_xerbla.o -L/usr/lib64/atlas -L. -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -llapack -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -lpython2.7 -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -Wall -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/python_xerbla.o -L/usr/lib64/atlas -L. -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -llapack -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -lpython2.7 -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so" failed with exit status 1
```

For some reason it's not finding `libpython2.7.so` even thought it's in the directory specified by `CFLAGS`. I even added the directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
gfairchild@cj-fe1 ~/code/packages/lib> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/projects/infmodels/gfairchild/packages/lib:/usr/projects/infmodels/ep_packages/db-4.3.28/lib:/usr/projects/infmodels/ep_packages/boost/lib:/usr/projects/infmodels/ep_packages/log4cpp/lib:/usr/projects/infmodels/gfairchild/packages/lib:/usr/projects/infmodels/ep_packages/db-4.3.28/lib:/usr/projects/infmodels/ep_packages/boost/lib:/usr/projects/infmodels/ep_packages/log4cpp/lib:/opt/OpenMPI/openmpi-1.4.3-gcc/lib64
```

What can I do to get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed it! Looking in the numpy-1.6.2 directory, I saw a file called `site.cfg.example`. Looking inside, I saw that you can specify library and include directories. I simply created a file called `site.cfg` whose contents are the following:

```
[DEFAULT]
library_dirs = /usr/projects/infmodels/gfairchild/packages/lib:/usr/local/lib
include_dirs = /usr/projects/infmodels/gfairchild/packages/include:/usr/local/include
```

That was all it took for it to finish building. m01's solution (adding the path to `LDFLAGS`) got me further, but it still errored out. The `site.cfg` file allowed it to finish building.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the `-L/some/path` option into `LDFLAGS` rather than `CFLAGS`. `CFLAGS` are [usually] passed to the compiler, `LDFLAGS` [usually] to the linker, and you're looking at a linker error :)

Incidentally, in this case the error appears just after a Fortran compiler error. You could try to supply the `-L` in `FCFLAGS` as well (even though it's not really a compiler, but a linker flag.. this is just in case you get really desperate for a hack).

Comment: Thanks! I actually just fixed it, though. I just added my solution as an answer.